# gPodder: "cannot open device" (iPod nano 5G)

Tags: 14.04, ipod, gpodder

I am trying to sync podcasts with my iPod using gPodder, but I keep getting the message "cannot open device".

In the preferences, I set the device type on iPod (obviously) and the mount point as "/media".

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? Please tell me if I have to provide more information (and how to obtain it - I'm a linux newbie).

Thank you very much for your attention!

Ubuntu 14.04 (MATE 1.8.2) --- gPodder 3.8.4 --- iPod nano 5G

(Update: I successfully added a podcast episode as a music file using Amarok. The iPod itself does not seem to be the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from the [gPodder Manual:](https://gpodder.github.io/docs/user-manual.html)

Devices Preferences

Click the Devices tab to see gPodder’s options for portable media player devices.

Device type: Choose the type of device from this drop-down list that matches your player. The available options are:

Filesystem-based - Choose this device if your media player is treated like a simple USB storage device, and media files are added by copying them to a directory on the device.

**Note that as of version 3.2.0, gPodder only supports syncing with filesystem-based devices. Check the user documentation for your device if you’re unsure what kind it is.**

*Mountpoint: Click this button to choose the mount point where your media player normally appears on your system.*